# Could an `analogWrite` command and its variable output values be used to power multiple leds with same intensity?

Tags: led, voltage-level, analogwrite

I seem to be getting the right response on single LED but with multiple LEDS or a relay connected LED strip the voltage outputs seem to be insuffiecient. 
What kind of analogWrite values does an LED respond to?

Comment: How are you driving your LED's electrically?  With multiples (in parallel) the current requirement will rapidly exceed what one micro can handle, so you probably need a transistor, FET, or driver IC to help out.  But you can still use the *information* from the PWM "analog out" pin.

Comment: replaced the bulb in this image with an LED strip. 
http://www.instructables.com/file/FXOD7OOHTVICRIN

and the pin 7 analogWrite values are perfect for single LED but dont produce results for this strip

Comment: You need to provide details of the strip.  They come in many forms, some requirung particular signals to drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single LEDs like the standard 5mm leds work from low voltages such as 1.7 - 2.1v, so can be directly driven via an Arduino pin (through a resistor to prevent excess current draw which would damage the pin).

LED strips such as automotive LED strips (12v) require the use of a relay if you are simply switching the LEDs on and off. You can't run the relay directly from an Arduino pin, you will need to use a transistor to act as a buffer between the relay and the Arduino to prevent damaging the Arduino. Instead of the motor and diode in the below diagram, you connect your 12v led strip.

[image: relay arduino connection]

If you want to control intensity, you will need to use a transistor, or a mosfet (mosfets are easier). You can then use AnalogWrite to control the intensity of the LEDs via the MOSFET. You will need to connect the control pin for the MOSFET to one of the PWM-capable pins on the Arduino (the pins which have the ~ mark next to them), otherwise you will only be able to switch the MOSFET on and off, similar to the Relay. This site has a good guide on how to do this with a [MOSFET](http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/). It also has a guide on how to use a transistor, but I can't include the link yet due to not enough reputation points. It shows both the code needed, and how to connect the components to the Arduino.

[image: mosfet arduino connection]